# VScode/WSL: Could not fetch remote environment & Failed to connect to the remote extension host server(Error:WebSocket Close with status code 1006)

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux, remote-server, wsl-2, vscode-remote

I downloaded the WSL Ubuntu on my Windows, and tried to link it to my VScode, but there are two errors pops up saying:

1.Coude not fetch remote environment
2.Failed to connect to the remote extension host server (Error: websocket close with status code 1006)

[here is what the error says](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OMehB.png)

[WSL targets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9l3n5.png)

[Ubuntu version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/elg9X.png)

[Extensions cannot be added as well](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qEscP.png)

I tryed so many methods from online as well:

1.reinstall VScode
2.shutdown/restart wsl
3.Remove .vscode-server in WSL (rm -rf ~/.vscode-server)
4.Restart my PC
5.Downgrade my VScode

But none of them work, I am wondering how can i fix this issue.